# Storing User Information after Deletion

Tags: database-design, delete

I am building a collaboration platform that focuses on being a knowledge base for teams and a big part of creating a knowledge base is storing historical information even when an employee has left. Based on this need I was wondering what modifications I should make to my database to allow the admin delete a user without worrying of detaching the users first name, last name and email from the record. The worry is that when users go back in time the record won't be attached to a user and no one will know who the original author is.

These were my thoughts on handling this, but there are definitely better approaches than what I have listed:

1. Add a column called `deleted_at` that will timestamp the deletion, but not remove the record from the `app_user` table.
2. Create a `deleted_user` table that stores a record on deletion from `app_user`.

Here is my table structure:

`app_user`:

```
app_user_id
first_name
last_name
email
password
picture
```

`blog_record`:

```
blog_id
title
content
app_user_id
```

`blog_record` has a `one-to-one` relationship with `app_user`

Comment: Why would you want to use a separate table for deleted users? This approach would prevent you from establishing a referential integrity constraint on the user ID. And is it really one-to-one? A user can only create one blog record?

Comment: I would go with your first choice and simply record the fact that a person is no longer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would perform what's known as a "soft delete", i.e. you don't actually delete the user from the table, but rather flag it as deleted.

This keeps your foreign key constraints intact, and you could probably even "recreate" the account if the user comes back at some point in the future, just by setting the "deleted" flag to false again.

For bonus points: remember that various privacy laws around the world regulate how much information you can save after a contract ends. When a user quits, I would probably update the personally identifiable information in the user table, so they are blank or anonymous.